# Copy file with rsync or scp over multiple level or hops of SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, scp, file-copying

I need to transfer around 4.2 GB of files from my `local computer` to a `server B`. However to ssh into server B, I need to ssh into `server A`.

Currently I'm copying files from my `local computer` to server A and then from `server A` to `server B`.

So the flow goes like this:

`rsync -avz --del ~/Desktop/abc/ <my-user-name>@<server-A>:~/abc`

`rsync -avz --del ~/Desktop/abc/ <my-user-name>@<server-B>:~/abc`

This is slow and copies 4.2 gb of data two times instead of one!

Can I transfer files with `rsync` from my local computer to directly `server B` ?

Comment: "copies 4.2 gb of data two times instead of one!" Well, since you're routing through server A, you'll always be transferring data "twice", once from local to server A, once from server A to server B (whether they can be simultaneous is another question). That's just the nature of routing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always use `ssh` with proxy command, which allows you to transfer files transparently. Using this config (~/.ssh/config):

```
Host <server-A>
    User <user-A>

Host <server-B>
    User <user-B>
    ProxyCommand ssh <server-A> -W %h:%p
```

You can call your rsync:

```
rsync -avz --del ~/Desktop/abc/ <server-B>:~/abc
```

The data will be only "routed" over the middle host.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use *port-forwarding* to forward the *ssh*/*rsync* port (generally port 22) from *server B* to alternate ports on *server A* so when you call `rsync -e "ssh -p altport" serverA:/sourcedir /destdir`, you are actually invoking rsync from `serverB`.

There are many good howtos available on StackExchange and other sites. For example:

- [**How to forward a port from one machine to
  another?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57721/how-to-forward-a-port-from-one-machine-to-another)
  or
- [**How To Forward Ports through a Linux Gateway with
  Iptables**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)

will get you started. Using port-forwarding, you are essentially using *serverA* as a pass-through host so you will only have to transfer your 4.2G once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy the files (and even folders) directly without making any intermediate copies on the *contact/login server*, which is by default the machine known to the outside world, or *contacted* to get access to a specific local network.

Below is a simple demonstration using `scp` without any unnecessary complications. On the local machine, simply do the following:

```
$ scp -r -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p your_username@contact-server.de" your_username@machine_name:/file/path/on/this/machine   ~/destination/path/to/save/the/copied/folder
```

- `-r` option instructs `scp` to copy the contents of the entire folder.
- *your_username* need not be the same on both machines.

If it is successful, you'll be asked for your *passwords* on both machines for authentication.

In the above command it is assumed that the typical way to access the machine named as "machine_name" would be via the contact server.

---

**Note:**
The above command also works for transferring data from a *source remote machine* (e.g. *s*) to a *target remote machine* (say *t*). In such a scenario, first `ssh` to the source remote machine (*s*) and navigate to the path where the data resides. After that you can simply think of/treat that remote machine as a *local/source machine* and then simply use the same `scp` command listed above for copying folders.

For copying individual files, just remove the `-r` option and provide the path to the specific file that you want to copy.